# How to expand this integrand as a geometric series and evaluate it?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I study Riemann's **Zeta** function.
This connection between these two functions (Zeta and Gamma) should become clear via the derivation of a so-called functional equation.

Starting point is this integral `Integrate[x^(s - 1)/(E^x*(1 - E^(-x))), {x, 0, Infinity}]` which I can't find easily in the functions database of MMA, but after evaluating the integral in MMA, i got a answer.
$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x^{s-1} e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}} \, dx$

I evaluate the integral and it turns out to be this integral: `ConditionalExpression[Gamma[s] PolyLog[s, 1], Re[s] > 1]`

The **PolyLog** function is defined as:     $\frac{\Gamma '(z)}{\Gamma (z)}$ ( the derivative of **Gamma(= EulerGamma)** function / Gamma Function)

How to expand integrand from $\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x^{s-1} e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}} \, dx$ function as geometric series and evaluate this?

Comment: Try: `MellinTransform[Exp[-x]/(1 - Exp[-x]), x, s, GenerateConditions -> True]`

Comment: @ Mariusz Iwaniuk , it gives the same answer as from @ Bob Hanlon

Comment: If you’re going to make me write out the integral by hand, instead of politely providing copyable code, then I don’t see why you cannot do the geometric series by hand (they’re easy, after all) and plug the terms into `Integrate[]`.

Comment: @ Michael E2, indeed i forgot to add the integral in the problem description

Comment: `Integrate[x^(s - 1)/(E^x*(1 - E^(-x))), {x, 0, Infinity}]Integrate[x^(s - 1)/(E^x*(1 - E^(-x))), {x, 0, Infinity}]`
Hint :expanding the integrand as a geometric series, evaluate 
This integral is not known by me, so wha to do ?

Comment: You can break down this code and see if the pieces help: `Integrate[SeriesCoefficient[x^(s - 1)/(E^x*(1 - E^(-x))) /. Power[E, p_] :> q^(-p/x), {q, 0, n}, Assumptions -> n >= 0] Exp[-n x], {x, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> n >= 0 && n \[Element] Integers && Re[s] > 0]`. The integral of a term of the geometric series is, after a simple substitution, a gamma function.

Comment: "The integral of a term of the geometric series is, after a simple substitution, a gamma function".
How to see this geometric serie ?

Comment: This another form of the startintegral is done by ?
`Assuming[Re[s] > 1, FullSimplify[x^(-1 + s)/(E^x*(1 - E^(-x))) == x^(s - 1)/(E^x*(1 - E^(-x)))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f[s_] = Integrate[x^(s - 1) E^-x/(1 - E^-x), {x, 0, Infinity}]

(* ConditionalExpression[Gamma[s] PolyLog[s, 1], Re[s] > 1] *)
```

To convert this to an expression in terms of [`Zeta`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Zeta.html), use either [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) or [`FunctionExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionExpand.html)

```
f[s] // FullSimplify

(* ConditionalExpression[Gamma[s] Zeta[s], Re[s] > 1] *)

f[s] // FunctionExpand

(* ConditionalExpression[Gamma[s] Zeta[s], Re[s] > 1] *)
```

**EDIT:** Graphically,

```
Plot[{PolyLog[s, 1], Zeta[s]}, {s, -1, 3},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {0.8, 0.2}]]
```

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

`Zeta[s]` is real for real `s` provided `s != 1`

```
FunctionDomain[Zeta[s], s]

(* s < 1 || s > 1 *)
```

`PolyLog[s, 1]` is only real for `s > 1`

```
FunctionDomain[PolyLog[s, 1], s]

(* s > 1 *)
```

The two functions are equal for `Re[s] > 1`

```
Assuming[Re[s] > 1, PolyLog[s, 1] == Zeta[s] // FullSimplify]

(* True *)
```

For series representations,

```
(seriesReps = 
    Last /@ (Entity["MathematicalFunction", "PolyLog"][
        "SeriesRepresentations"] /. {Sum :> Inactive[Sum], 
        Inactivate :> HoldForm})) // 
  Column[#, Frame -> All] & // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

However, a series expansion is not needed to evaluate `PolyLog`

```
Table[{s, PolyLog[s, 1]}, {s, 1.25, 3.0, 0.25}]

(* {{1.25, 4.59511}, {1.5, 2.61238}, {1.75, 1.96232}, {2., 1.64493}, {2.25, 
  1.46021}, {2.5, 1.34149}, {2.75, 1.26019}, {3., 1.20206}} *)
```

Comment: What does this graph suggest?
That part of the Zeta function coincides with the PolyLog function ?

Comment: The expressions for `f[s]` indicated that `PolyLog[s, 1]` was equivalent to `Zeta[s]` for `Re[s] > 1`. The plot verifies this for `s > 1`, i.e., the dashed curve (`Zeta[s]`) lines on top of the blue curve (`Polylog[s, 1]`) in that region.

Comment: From the calculation in MMA follows that functions  `PolyLog[s]` =   `Zeta[s]` , so they have same graph then.

Comment: `PolyLog[s,1] == Zeta[s]  iff Re[s] > 1`. As shown in the plot, they are not generally equal.

Comment: How do you check this  : the general comparison gives not true then?
If both plots are not equal for a specified domain.
How to know that expressions are true?

Comment: @ Bob Hanlon, thanks , very helpful to handle functions

Answer (score 2):

Using $\frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}=\frac{1}{e^x-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-n x}$:

$$
f(s) =\int_0^{\infty}dx\,x^{s-1}\frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}
=\int_0^{\infty}dx\,x^{s-1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-n x}
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}dx\,x^{s-1}e^{-n x}
$$

Using $\int_0^{\infty}dx\,x^{s-1}e^{-n x}=n^{-s}\Gamma(s)$ which follows from the definition of the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function):

```
Integrate[x^(s - 1) E^(-n x), {x, 0, ∞}]
(*    n^-s Gamma[s] if Re[n]>0 && Re[s]>0    *)
```

$$
f(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-s}\Gamma(s)
= \Gamma(s)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-s}
$$

Using the definition of the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function):

```
Sum[n^-s, {n, 1, ∞}]
(*    Zeta[s]    *)
```

$$
f(s)=\Gamma(s)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-s}
= \Gamma(s)\zeta(s)
$$

Comment: thanks for showing this. The polylog function is the product of two functions.